# How to remove duplicate selected items and replace with quantity

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have been working on this project for school. It is a supply list for grades K-J. Each grade has #2 pencils and various other similar items. When you select one item in Kindergarten (#2 pencils) and select the same item in say Fifth Grade, then generate the list I do not need #2 pencils to show up twice, but only once with a quantity number next to it.

I am sure it has something to do with an if statement, but I'm still trying to master those.

Here is the jquery mobile part

```
<body>
<section class="header_default footer_default" data-role="page" id="setup" data-title="Setup">
<article data-role="content">
    <div class="loaded"></div>
    <p id="count"></p>
    <form>
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="hoursName">
            <legend><strong>Kindergarten Supply List:</strong></legend>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-group" name="checkboxsupply" id="1" value="(48 Quanity) #2 6-sided pencils (sharpened preferred)" >
            <label for="1">(48 Quanity) #2 6-sided pencils (sharpened preferred)</label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-group" name="checkboxsupply" id="2" value="(2 Quanity) Red pencils">
            <label for="2">(2 Quanity) Red Pencils</label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-group" name="checkboxsupply" id="3" value="(1 Quanity) Pack of pink erasers">
            <label for="3">(1 Quanity) Pack of pink erasers</label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-group" name="checkboxsupply" id="4" value="(1 Quanity) Box of Kleenex (tissue)">
            <label for="4">(1 Quanity) Box of Kleenex (tissue)</label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-group" name="checkboxsupply" id="5" value="(1 Quanity) Pack of pencil cap erasers">
            <label for="5">(1 Quanity) Pack of pencil cap erasers</label>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="hoursName">
            <legend><strong>First Grade Supply List:</strong></legend>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxsupply" id="1" value="(48 Quanity) #2 6-sided pencils (sharpened preferred)" >
            <label for="1">(48 Quanity) #2 6-sided pencils (sharpened preferred)</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxsupply" id="2" value="(2 Quanity) Red pencils">
            <label for="2">(2 Quanity) Red Pencils</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxsupply" id="3" value="(1 Quanity) Pack of pink erasers">
            <label for="3">(1 Quanity) Pack of pink erasers</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxsupply" id="4" value="(1 Quanity) Box of Kleenex (tissue)">
            <label for="4">(1 Quanity) Box of Kleenex (tissue)</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxsupply" id="5" value="(1 Quanity) Pack of pencil cap erasers">
            <label for="5">(1 Quanity) Pack of pencil cap erasers</label>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="hoursName">
            <legend><strong>Second Grade Supply List:</strong></legend>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxsupply" id="1" value="(48 Quanity) #2 6-sided pencils (sharpened preferred)" >
            <label for="1">(48 Quanity) #2 6-sided pencils (sharpened preferred)</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxsupply" id="2" value="(2 Quanity) Red pencils">
            <label for="2">(2 Quanity) Red Pencils</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxsupply" id="3" value="(1 Quanity) Pack of pink erasers">
            <label for="3">(1 Quanity) Pack of pink erasers</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxsupply" id="4" value="(1 Quanity) Box of Kleenex (tissue)">
            <label for="4">(1 Quanity) Box of Kleenex (tissue)</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxsupply" id="5" value="(1 Quanity) Pack of pencil cap erasers">
            <label for="5">(1 Quanity) Pack of pencil cap erasers</label>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="hoursName">
            <legend><strong>Third Grade Supply List:</strong></legend>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxsupply" id="1" value="(48 Quanity) #2 6-sided pencils (sharpened preferred)" >
            <label for="1">(48 Quanity) #2 6-sided pencils (sharpened preferred)</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxsupply" id="2" value="(2 Quanity) Red pencils">
            <label for="2">(2 Quanity) Red Pencils</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxsupply" id="3" value="(1 Quanity) Pack of pink erasers">
            <label for="3">(1 Quanity) Pack of pink erasers</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxsupply" id="4" value="(1 Quanity) Box of Kleenex (tissue)">
            <label for="4">(1 Quanity) Box of Kleenex (tissue)</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxsupply" id="5" value="(1 Quanity) Pack of pencil cap erasers">
            <label for="5">(1 Quanity) Pack of pencil cap erasers</label>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="hoursName">
            <legend><strong>Forth Grade Supply List:</strong></legend>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxsupply" id="1" value="(48 Quanity) #2 6-sided pencils (sharpened preferred)" >
            <label for="1">(48 Quanity) #2 6-sided pencils (sharpened preferred)</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxsupply" id="2" value="(2 Quanity) Red pencils">
            <label for="2">(2 Quanity) Red Pencils</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxsupply" id="3" value="(1 Quanity) Pack of pink erasers">
            <label for="3">(1 Quanity) Pack of pink erasers</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxsupply" id="4" value="(1 Quanity) Box of Kleenex (tissue)">
            <label for="4">(1 Quanity) Box of Kleenex (tissue)</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxsupply" id="5" value="(1 Quanity) Pack of pencil cap erasers">
            <label for="5">(1 Quanity) Pack of pencil cap erasers</label>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="hoursName">
            <legend><strong>Fifth Grade Supply List:</strong></legend>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxsupply" id="1" value="(48 Quanity) #2 6-sided pencils (sharpened preferred)" >
            <label for="1">(48 Quanity) #2 6-sided pencils (sharpened preferred)</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxsupply" id="2" value="(2 Quanity) Red pencils">
            <label for="2">(2 Quanity) Red Pencils</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxsupply" id="3" value="(1 Quanity) Pack of pink erasers">
            <label for="3">(1 Quanity) Pack of pink erasers</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxsupply" id="4" value="(1 Quanity) Box of Kleenex (tissue)">
            <label for="4">(1 Quanity) Box of Kleenex (tissue)</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxsupply" id="5" value="(1 Quanity) Pack of pencil cap erasers">
            <label for="5">(1 Quanity) Pack of pencil cap erasers</label>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="hoursName">
            <legend><strong>Sixth Grade Supply List:</strong></legend>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxsupply" id="1" value="(48 Quanity) #2 6-sided pencils (sharpened preferred)" >
            <label for="1">(48 Quanity) #2 6-sided pencils (sharpened preferred)</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxsupply" id="2" value="(2 Quanity) Red pencils">
            <label for="2">(2 Quanity) Red Pencils</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxsupply" id="3" value="(1 Quanity) Pack of pink erasers">
            <label for="3">(1 Quanity) Pack of pink erasers</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxsupply" id="4" value="(1 Quanity) Box of Kleenex (tissue)">
            <label for="4">(1 Quanity) Box of Kleenex (tissue)</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxsupply" id="5" value="(1 Quanity) Pack of pencil cap erasers">
            <label for="5">(1 Quanity) Pack of pencil cap erasers</label>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <button class="ui-btn ui-corner-all Create">Create List</button>


</article><!--content-->
</section>
```

Here is the javascript that I have

```
<div data-role="page" id="nameList"></div>
<script id="jsbin-javascript">
$(".Create").on("click", function() {
    var selectedValues = "";
    $checkedCheckboxes = $("input:checkbox[name=checkboxsupply]:checked");
    $checkedCheckboxes.each(function () {
        $('#nameList').append('<li>' + $(this).val() + '</li>');
    });
    window.location = "#nameList";
});
</script>
```

Any suggestions would be great, I have tried using jquery as a way to count up the quantity but had no luck.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can't change the markup any, here's a somewhat hacky way you could do this :)

```
  $(".Create").on("click", function() {
    var valuesToListItemMap = {};
    $('#nameList').text("");

    $checkedCheckboxes = $("input:checkbox[name=checkboxsupply]:checked");
    $checkedCheckboxes.each(function () {
      var value = $(this).val();
      var element;

      if (valuesToListItemMap[value]) {
        element = valuesToListItemMap[value];

        var newCount = parseInt(element.data('count')) + 1;

        element.data('count', newCount);
        element.text(value + ' ' + newCount + ' were selected');
      } else {
        element = $('<li>' + value + '</li>');
        element.data('count', 1);

        $('#nameList').append(element);

        valuesToListItemMap[value] = element;
      }
    });

    window.location = "#nameList";
  });
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/yanaju/4/edit

Comment: Cool how it change the quantity in the () but I would like to keep those numbers the same because that keeps it simple, looking for like that counts the amount of checks of a certain item.

(48 Quantity) #2 6-sided pencils (sharpened preferred) 3 were checked

Comment: I appreciate that, I was close to getting the quantity there but i could not remove the duplicates.   Thanks again

Comment: Actually pardon, I think I misunderstood the "# selected" bit. Give me a second to make one more adjustment.

Comment: Good to go. That actually simplified things a bit. :)

Comment: It looks good I will have to check out your code to see what you did when i get home or tomorrow morning, thanks for answering so quickly.